# I HAVE to use pop() method in Python3 over a dictionary

Tags: python

I HAVE to use pop() method in Python3 to delete all states that starts with 'M'. Can't figure out how to keep the size of the dictionary.

```
states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MO': 'Missouri',
        'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'MS': 'Mississippi',
}

for key, val in states.items():
    if key[0] == 'M':
        states.pop(key, val)
```

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [45], in <cell line: 62>()
     60 # your code here
     61 newdic = {}
---> 62 for key, val in states.items():
     63     if key[0] == 'M':
     64         states.pop(key,val)

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Why do you **HAVE** to use `pop`, exactly?

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips like starting with your own research and how to write a good title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the dictionary, iterate over it, and pop from the original dictionary.

The code:

```
 states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MO': 'Missouri',
        'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'MS': 'Mississippi',
}

for key, val in states.copy().items():
    if key[0] == 'M':
        states.pop(key)
```

Output:

```
{'AK': 'Alaska', 'AL': 'Alabama', 'AR': 'Arkansas'}
```

Comment: Thank yoy Ryan. I have to check out how to work with sets. I'm unable to upvote right now but I did it for both questions:

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 2):

If, as you say, you **must** use pop, then create a separate set of the key values and iterate over that.  Altering the size of something you are iterating over is a big no-no.

```
states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MO': 'Missouri',
        'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'MS': 'Mississippi',
}

for key in set(states.keys()):
    if key[0] == 'M':
        states.pop(key)

print(states)
```

#### Output:

```
{'AK': 'Alaska', 'AL': 'Alabama', 'AR': 'Arkansas'}
```

Comment: This is much better than creating a whole new dict as the other answer suggests. However I'd go with a tuple instead of a set, as its creation should be a tad faster